# List Count is 0 in event handler but 3 in Update

Tags: c#, events, list, xna

I have created an event handler, which is called every update for testing purposes.
My problem is that when I find the Count of a List in my class, it's 0 inside the Event Handler but 3 in the update method. Why would this be happening if I'm not modifying the list an anywhere but in the LoadContent method?

Code for event handler:

```
if (MaxTiles.X * row + col < TileList.Count)
{
    selectedTileIndex = (int)(row * MaxTiles.X + col);
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(selectedTileIndex.ToString());
}
System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(TileList.Count);
```

EDIT: I have tested out the method when I call it from the object itself, and it gives me a count of 3! Is there something I don't know about C# events?

EDIT: If it helps, the event is being fired in another class.

EDIT: I found a (very smelly) workaround, but I'm curious as to why this would be happening.

Comment: You should show a little more code. Can't tell what might be different from just what you posted.

Answer (score 0):

It might be helpful to have slightly more information for something like this, however I'll take a shot in the dark.

Perhaps the first time you are viewing it within the event handler it had just been instantiated? If not, is the LoadContent event being called at all, it might be helpful to throw a breakpoint in and attempt to step through the process.

Comment: Actually it gives me a count of 3 in the update method so it does have the items, the event handler just can't see them

Comment: Also, I said in my question that the handler is called on every update

Comment: Just as a possibly unrelated issue while debugging, in your WriteLine statements, it might be helpful to add a description, such as "Current Tile : 0", and "Tile Count : 0" respectively. If this is what you are using to keep track of these.

Comment: I usually do, but in this case the `locals` list shows the count to be 0 as well, but only in the event handler